# inertia scrolling algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, user-interface, math

Is there any algorithm for inertia scrolling like Mac has. I want to write a java application which would implement that algorithm. this is just a fun little project.

any help would greatly appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just store the time when the user clicked and released the mouse. Use those times to make a velocity in terms of lines to scroll per second. Then add a decay to the speed; a deceleration if you will - you can either have it decrease at a constant rate, or go for a set period of time.